# How to start a service on Ubuntu 20.04 via systemctl?

Tags: ubuntu, systemctl

I have an instance running ubuntu 20.04. I've logged into the console via the online GUI 'connect' tool. On the ubuntu instance I've added a service file with below contents:

`linux_setup`:

```
[Unit]
Description=my app
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=ubuntu
ExecStart=python3 app.py file:///$PWD/LOG --port 8080

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I now want to start this within my instance. To do so I perform the below steps:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-1-50:~$ ls
app-folder
ubuntu@ip-172-31-1-50:~$ cd app-folder
ubuntu@ip-172-31-1-50:~/app-folder$ ls
LICENSE  LOG  README.md  datasource  app.py  linux_setup.service  requirements.txt  test
ubuntu@ip-172-31-1-50:~/app-folder$ sudo systemctl start linux_setup
Failed to start linux_setup.service: Unit linux_setup.service not found.
ubuntu@ip-172-31-1-50:~/app-folder$
```

As evident, it seems like the linux_setup.service is not found - yet it should be there. How do I correctly start up this setup file?

Comment: Ask this on https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: This has no link to EC2 - abstract that info out plus not a question for SO, try https://unix.stackexchange.com/ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using below method to download a unit file and deploy it:

```
sudo wget [your_file_url]
sudo cp service_name.service /etc/systemd/system/
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start service_name
sudo systemctl enable service_name
sudo journalctl -f -u service_name
```